# How to change background color of a UIImagePickerController's Table View?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

[image]

Using the `UIImagePickerController` to bring up the following window.
Am able to change the navigation bar color and their text attributes no problem.

How to change the background of this table view's cells AND the background color of this tableView?

Basically all the area that has been painted red is the area I'm trying to change the color of. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImagePickerController is not intended to be modified. It should have the system default style and if you modified that, your app will get rejected.

If you want to customize it, you need to look at some custom image picker, not the one that is provided to you by default.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I wasn't aware that the app would get rejected had I attempted to change the system default style. Your answer helped me.